# jQuery selector for "all not first in a div preceded by a object with class"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

Here is a sample of what I have in HTML:

```
<span class="a">Test</span>
<div class="b">
  <div id="x_ABC">ABC must NOT be hidden</div>
  <div id="x_DEF">DEF must be hidden</div>
  <div id="x_GHI">GHI must be hidden</div>
  <div id="JKL">JKL must NOT be hidden</div>
</div>
```

All I want is to hide with jQuery all the divs with an id starting with "x" inside the div with class "b" preceded by a html tag with a class "a".

I tried this code :

```
$('.a + div.b div[id^=x]:gt(0)').hide()
```

But it doesn't do what I want. Does anyone know how to fix the selector using only the class "a", "b" and "id^=x"?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quotes in attribute selectors are mandatory:

```
$('.a + div.b div[id^="x"]:gt(0)').hide()
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/EkBqw/)

For performance reasons, you might want to use [`.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/):

```
$('.a + div.b div[id^="x"]').slice(1).hide()
```

Comment: Well, without quotes it worked (even if they are mandatory) when I wrote that : `$('.a + div.b div[id^="x"]').hide()` (it hid all the concerned divs). Nevertheless I add the quote...
I found my exact problem. I site I modify uses jQuery1.4.4 and your example doesn't work with that old version. Gotta update now! Thank you!

Comment: @Guile: ? What do you mean? The selector you just described has quotes around the value...

Comment: Moreover, thank you for the performance tip with .slice(1) ! This a great one!

Comment: @Guile: Ah yeah, in old jQuery versions, it worked without the quotes. Regarding `slice`: It is just so that jQuery can pass the selector to `querySelectorAll` in recent browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes around the `x`: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Just a more functional alternative:

```
$('div.b').each(function(_, b) {
    var $b = $(b);

    if( $b.prev().hasClass('a') ) {
        $b.children().slice(1).filter(function() { return this.id.charAt(0) === 'x' }).hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's as simple as this

```
$('.a + .b > *[id^="x"]:nth-child(n+2)').hide();
```